# How to prevent the user from going back to login page after logged in

Tags: angular, authentication

In my angular app I have login function.
here is my authservice.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthserviceService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    login(data):Observable<any>{
    console.log("I am server");
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login/',data);
  }
}
```

here is my loginComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthserviceService } from 'src/app/authservice.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'sl8-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
   })
   export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   formGroup : FormGroup;
   constructor(private authService :AuthserviceService, private _router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }
  initForm(){
    this.formGroup =new FormGroup({
     email : new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      password : new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    })
  }


  loginProcess(){
    if(this.formGroup.valid){      
       this.authService.login(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(results => {
          this._router.navigate(['/home'])
       }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
           const message = error.error.detail;
          console.log(message);
          if (error.status === 400)
            alert('Invalid form inputs')
          else if (error.status === 401)
             alert('Invalid Credentials Provided')
       });
    } 
  }

}
```

Below is postman result when I entered correct credentials.

> "email": "test@gmail.com", "tokens": "{'refresh': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYxMzAxNTI5NSwianRpIjoiMzliNzY0N2ExMjVhNDI2M2E2MTVlYjhiZmQ4ZTgyYzgiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.-mEy9rWyRm7lXsnG-JfoGFgn4GrLrOa-hAkBm0gyb8s', 'access': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjExODE3Njk1LCJqdGkiOiIwMTExNmU2NWI0OTM0YTcwYmJiNGM2ZjhkZDEyZTU4YSIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.Raf38'}" }

Login function work fine. But the problem is when I logged in I'll redirect to the home page. But If I click on back button It again go to the login page. How can I prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a **Guard** and make use of [`canActivate`](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) which redirects to */home* whenever */login* is being accessed while user is already logged in.

LoginGuard:

```
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        // redirect logic goes here
    }
}
```

In your router config:

```
{
    path: '/login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginGuard],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a routing file with path '' and canActivate property

Answer (score 0):

Pass auth token to login page everytime and redirect if token is not empty.